# how do i filter from json (get request) output saved in a variable in python

Tags: python, json

The output of a get request is saved in a variable.
How do i filter the data in the variable to show only the information I need?

This is how I'm retrieving the json:

```
import requests
url = "https://"+nsip+"/nitro/v1/config/server/"

headers = {
        'Cache-Control': "no-cache"
    }
response = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers, auth=(usr,pwd), verify=False)
jsdata = response.json()
print(json.dumps(jsdata, indent=3))
```

Output:

```
{
    "errorcode": 0,
    "message": "Done",
    "severity": "NONE",
    "server": [
        {
            "name": "server1",
            "ipaddress": "192.168.134.28",
            "boundtd": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "server2",
            "ipaddress": "192.168.134.18",
            "boundtd": "0"
        },
        {
            "name": "server3",
            "ipaddress": "192.168.134.9",
            "boundtd": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to filter and print only "name" and ignore the rest of it:

```
"name": "server1"
"name": "server2"
```

If I do:

```
servers = jsdata['server'][1]['name']
print(servers)
```

It only prints the first server name.

Also tried:

```
for i in jsdata:
        query = ({'i["name"]'})
print(query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get a list of `dict` as result:

```
>>> [{'name': srv['name']} for srv in jsdata['server']]

[{'name': 'server1'}, {'name': 'server2'}, {'name': 'server3'}]
```

Or to get a list of `str` as result:

```
>>> [srv['name'] for srv in jsdata['server']]

['server1', 'server2', 'server3']
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Yuan! That indeed helped to print the server names. Is there a way to get rid of   '{' and '}' in the output?

Comment: Amazing! getting the list via `str` gives me exactly what i need. Thank you!

Comment: my pleasure to help